# Selective Aggregation SQL; Not the regular Group by

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregation

My Dataset looks like this . Alert levels follow a priority :

```
C > O > W
```

The open and closed Dates follow the alert level priorities . 
Eg: An Alert level 'W' with an Closed Date greater than a Open Date of an Alert Level 'O' , will take the closed date of the open date of C. (I did this part using CTE) the resultant Data set is as below. Now , the challenge is the eliminate 2 consecutive same alert levels to only one with min of the 2 open dates and max of the 2 closed dates between them ( read first 2 'W')

Dataset :

```
ID  axlenumber  alertlevel  closeReason         OpenDate        closeddate
100 1           W           HIGHER_LEVEL_ALERT  10/15/2008 0:00 1/27/2009 0:00
100 1           W           HIGHER_LEVEL_ALERT  1/22/2009 0:00  1/27/2009 0:00
100 1           O           REPAIR              1/27/2009 0:00  3/27/2009 0:00
100 1           C           REPAIR              1/27/2009 0:00  3/27/2009 0:00
100 1           W           HIGHER_LEVEL_ALERT  5/27/2012 0:00  8/18/2012 0:00
100 1           W           REPAIR              5/27/2012 0:00  8/18/2012 0:00
100 1           C           REPAIR              5/27/2012 0:00  8/18/2012 0:00
100 1           W           HIGHER_LEVEL_ALERT  6/22/2016 0:00  7/21/2017 0:00
100 1           O           HIGHER_LEVEL_ALERT  7/2/2017  0:00  11/15/2017 0:00
100 1           C           REPAIR              7/21/2017 0:00  11/15/2017 0:00
```

My desired Dataset should look like:

```
ID  axlenumber  alertlevel  closeReason         OpenDate        closeddate
100 1           W           HIGHER_LEVEL_ALERT  10/15/2008 0:00 1/27/2009 0:00

100 1           O           REPAIR              1/27/2009 0:00  1/27/2009 0:00
100 1           C           REPAIR              1/27/2009 0:00  3/27/2009 0:00

100 1           W           REPAIR              5/27/2012 0:00  5/27/2012 0:00
100 1           C           REPAIR              5/27/2012 0:00  8/18/2012 0:00
100 1           W           HIGHER_LEVEL_ALERT  6/22/2016 0:00  7/2/2017 0:00
100 1           O           HIGHER_LEVEL_ALERT  7/2/2017  0:00  7/21/2017 0:00
100 1           C           REPAIR              7/21/2017 0:00  11/15/2017 0:00
```

Thanks in Advance Team,
Arvin

Comment: Someone please help me with the edit and make it look like a dataset. Am not able to. Thanks and my apologies

Comment: You could make it look like a dataset using create table ..., insert into ... statements. SqLFiddle would help you on that.

Comment: So you're saying that the first two rows of sample data are "consecutive", closing on 1/27/09 and opening on 1/22/09, and should be combined. The desired result row covers 10/15/08 to 1/27/09, not 10/15/08 to 3/27/09 as I would expect if the rows were combined. What am I missing? Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @HABO-- Thats my typo : its 1/27/2009 . My apologies.

Comment: Okay. And ["consecutive"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/consecutive) means "overlapping in any way"? The fifth and sixth input rows are combined because they are both `alertlevel` "W" and happen to have identical dates. The combination has a `closeReason` that is the shortest of the two rows' values, i.e. "REPAIR" rather than "HIGHER_LEVEL_ALERT", or is there some other basis for the choice?

Comment: @HABO- The close reason doesnt alter anything. Thanks :)

Comment: Any help here guys ? Still stuck at this logic. thanks

Comment: I removed the contradicting tags `tsql` and `plsql`. Please add the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are actually using.

Comment: Not sure if this question is visible to the SQL experts ? Any sugestions on how to make it visible ?

Comment: Any help experts ?